# Apache Virtual Host (CSS & Javascript not being found)

Tags: apache, virtual, lamp

I am using a LAMP on Oracle Virtual Box. Everything was working great until I went into the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and altered something in the Virtual Host file. I don't have a back up and I am not sure what I did. The documentRoot is being found and the index.php is being loaded. However, all of my CSS and Javacsript files are returning a 404 so I basically get an unstyled page with text and images. All of my CSS and JS is located in /var/www/retirenetDev/retirenet/web/ where "web" is the document root, seen below. Everything is being correctly re-written to index.php, but even the static css files?. I'm just guessing by what I see in the access logs. **I'm pretty sure the code I removed involved the Re-write. I removed a couple lines, then the site broke.**

**Here is my Virtual Host:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName retirenet.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/retirenetDev/retirenet/web/
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/retirenetDev/retirenet/web/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        </Directory>
         RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(fckeditor/)
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    Alias /fckeditor "/home/open/retirenet/web/fckeditor/"
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

**And here is my apache access log when loading the page:**

```
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /c/fonts.x6x.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /s/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.0-min.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /i/spinner.gif HTTP/1.1" 301 380 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /s/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1-min.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /i/top100_new.jpg HTTP/1.1" 301 383 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /i/close.gif HTTP/1.1" 301 378 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /i/spinner.gif/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /i/top100_new.jpg/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:34 -0500] "GET /i/close.gif/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:33:42 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14167 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /c/fonts.x6x.css HTTP/1.1" 301 383 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /s/jquery.center.js HTTP/1.1" 301 386 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /c/new_responsive.x6x.css HTTP/1.1" 301 392 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /c/fonts.x6x.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /c/style.x6x.css HTTP/1.1" 301 382 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /s/jquery-2.1.4.min.js HTTP/1.1" 301 389 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /c/listings.x6x.css HTTP/1.1" 301 386 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /s/retscripts.x7x.js HTTP/1.1" 301 386 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /c/listings.x6x.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3228 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.120 - - [20/Dec/2015:10:52:04 -0500] "GET /s/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1-min.js HTTP/1.1" 301 401 "http://retirenet.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106
```

Any idea as to what the issue could be? There are no errors in the apache error logs. **The only errors I see are in my Firebug:**

```
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/retscripts.x7x.js/"
/s/rets...x7x.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.center.js/"
/s/jque...ter.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.0-min.js/"
/s/jque...min.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1-min.js/"
/s/jque...min.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/i/top100_new.jpg/"
/i/top1...ew.jpg/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.cookie.js/"
/s/jque...kie.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/i/spinner.gif/"
/i/spinner.gif/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/c/new_responsive.x6x.css/"
/c/new_...6x.css/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery-2.1.4.min.js/"
/s/jque...min.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/c/listings.x6x.css/"
/c/list...6x.css/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/c/fonts.x6x.css/"
/c/fonts.x6x.css/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/c/style.x6x.css/"
/c/style.x6x.css/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/i/close.gif/"
/i/close.gif/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.center.js/"
/s/jque...ter.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.0-min.js/"
/s/jque...min.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1-min.js/"
/s/jque...min.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/jquery.cookie.js/"
/s/jque...kie.js/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://retirenet.dev/s/retscripts.x7x.js/"
```

So basically, I can cruise the wesbite just fine. All data from DB is being loaded correctly. All pages are just unstyled and broken because JS & CSS is not loading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since all your images, css and javascript seem to be in their respective  subdirectory, you could replace :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(fckeditor/)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

By :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(fckeditor/)
RewriteCond $1 !^(c|i|s)/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will exclude all content under /c/, /i/ and /s/ subdirectories from being routed through /index.php.

You can achieve the same result by matching file extension :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(fckeditor/)
RewriteCond $1 !(\.js|\.css|\.jpg|\.png\.gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```